# "Wait.. screen" on safe mode loop

Tags: windows, windows-update, infinite-loop

After some windows update, when i boot up i have please wait screen only.

I did some googling and wanted to try safe mode (shift+F8) but even after i pick safe mode (presing 4 i submenu) it still gives me please wait screen - nothing more.

I also tired sfc from comand proprt but it ends on 100% and gives me message - Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation

What else i can do, i dont want to instal fresh OS coz i have too many improtent things on it.

Comment: The same has happened to me twice, both times the only option was a reinstall, but was able to keep my files.

Comment: thanks for your answer!! Hmm... maybe with hirens there is some chance??